# Append rows from one group to another group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have gotten two dataframes, A and B. I have created groups on both of them and would like to append rows from dataframe B to dataframe A in the same group. And the ordering is important.

These are the dataframes I have:\

**DataFrame A**

```
            Name   Sales
Datetime
2021-09-01  Amy    10000
2021-09-02  Amy    5000
2021-09-03  Amy    8500
2021-09-01  Joyce  2400
2021-09-02  Joyce  6500
2021-09-03  Joyce  5700
```

**DataFrame B**

```
            Name   Sales
Datetime
2021-09-04  Amy    11000
2021-09-05  Amy    5600
2021-09-06  Amy    8700
2021-09-04  Joyce  8800
2021-09-05  Joyce  5400
2021-09-06  Joyce  12000
```

What I expect:

```
            Name   Sales
Datetime
2021-09-01  Amy    10000
2021-09-02  Amy    5000
2021-09-03  Amy    8500
2021-09-04  Amy    11000
2021-09-05  Amy    5600
2021-09-06  Amy    8700
2021-09-01  Joyce  2400
2021-09-02  Joyce  6500
2021-09-03  Joyce  5700
2021-09-04  Joyce  8800
2021-09-05  Joyce  5400
2021-09-06  Joyce  12000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort on both fields using:

out = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values(['Name','Datetime'])

Comment: The order of the values inside sort_values is important when you have from than 1 field you want to order. It's not the same .sort_values(['Datetime','Name'] than .sort_Values['Name','Datetime]

Answer (score 1):

Using Append statement to combine 2 df and sort :

```
dfA.append(dfB, ignore_index=True).sort_values(by=['Name','Datetime'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat` two data frames then `sort_idnex` + `sort_values`

```
out = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index().sort_values('Name')
             Name  Sales
Datetime                
2021-09-01    Amy  10000
2021-09-02    Amy   5000
2021-09-03    Amy   8500
2021-09-04    Amy  11000
2021-09-05    Amy   5600
2021-09-06    Amy   8700
2021-09-01  Joyce   2400
2021-09-02  Joyce   6500
2021-09-03  Joyce   5700
2021-09-04  Joyce   8800
2021-09-05  Joyce   5400
2021-09-06  Joyce  12000
```

Comment: It should be work, however, the index 'Datetime' was not sorted correctly. For example, the first index is '2021-09-03', then '2021-09-01'.  Would it be related to the 'Datetime' format? I have set in the format of '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: While I do not add `.sort_index().sort_values('Name')`, it works, but the 'Name' will not be sorted in alphabetical order